# Find all with conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have 3 models. LimitType, LimitGroup and LimitGroupValue.

```
class LimitGroupValue < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :limit_group
  belongs_to :limit_type

end
```

I have the limit_group object (has many limit_group_values) and I want to find all limit_group_values which belong to a limit_type with a certain attribute value(code to be 'wager min').

I tried with:

```
@group.limit_group_values.find(:all, conditions: { limit_type: {code: 'WAGER_MIN'}})

@group.limit_group_values.find(:all, conditions: "limit_type.code = 'WAGER_MIN'")
```

I can't really seem to find a way. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. :Using rails 2.

Comment: @TheFabio "WAGER_MIN" is a code column from LimitType table

Comment: I was writing an answer for rails 4... v2 is out of my league...

Answer (score 1):

Try below -

```
@group.limit_group_values.find(:all, :joins => :limit_type , :conditions => [ "limit_type.code = ?", 'WAGER_MIN']).to_a
```

Comment: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "limit_type"

Comment: you will have to join :limit_type also, I have updated the answer. You should have has_many association in LimitGroup and LimitType models also.

Comment: hmm.. same error. here's the sql output: SELECT "limit_group_values".* FROM "limit_group_values"   INNER JOIN "limit_types" ON "limit_types".id = "limit_group_values".limit_type_id  WHERE ("limit_group_values".limit_group_id = 1 AND (limit_type.code = 'WAGER_MIN')). I don't want it to assume the limit_group_id is 1. Just find the one with the code attribute "WAGER_MIN"

Comment: For postgresql there would be some issues with double quota and single quota when we run query. try your query with join and `to_a`. ie. `@group.limit_group_values.find(:all, :joins => :limit_type, conditions: { limit_type: {code: 'WAGER_MIN'}}).to_a`